# Probability of throwing same sequence of 13 heads or tails

Tags: probability, self-study

Simple (I hope) probability question I'd love it if someone could answer for me.

You flip a coin 13 times (two outcomes: heads or tails).

Before the coin tossing, I've written down the 'winning sequence', eg. a random sequence of 13 outcomes, heads or tails for each toss.

For example: Heads, Heads, Tails, Heads, Tails, Tails, Tails, Heads, Tails, Heads, Heads, Tails, Heads.

What are the chances of someone tossing the coin and getting the same sequence (heads or tails in the exact same sequence) as me?

Comment: Is the coin fair? What are your thoughts on this? What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: As an addition to cardinal's comments.  You might want to try experimenting with a smaller number than 13, try with just three or so to simplify the question until you get a feel for it.

Comment: Lisic's comment is the key to a lot of probability problems. Simplify them until you can list all the outcomes -- that will help you see the pattern.   Try it with just 3, and draw out a decision tree diagram.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a fair coin: $(1/2)^{13}$. $1/2$ that you have the first correct, multiplied by $1/2$ that you have the second correct, ...

Comment: (+1) But this was tagged as homework so you're not encouraged to just give the full answer.

Comment: (sorry - didn't know that rule)